# Why does this regular expression not work?

Tags: python, html, regex

I have a function that parses HTML code so it is easy to read and write with. In order to do this I must split the string with multiple delimiters and as you can see I have used `re.split()` and I cannot find a better solution. However, when I submit some HTML such as [this](http://pastebin.com/cUgcfZeE), it has absolutely no effect. This has lead me to believe that my regular expression is incorrectly written. What should be there instead?

```
def parsed(data):
    """Removes junk from the data so it can be easily processed."""
    data = str(data)
    # This checks for a cruft and removes it if it exists.
    if re.search("b'", data):
        data = data[2:-1]
    lines = re.split(r'\r|\n', data)  # This clarifies the lines for writing.
    return lines
```

This isn't a duplicate if you find a similar question, I've been crawling around for ages and it still doesn't work.

Comment: *I have a function that parses HTML code so it is easy to read and write with.* Ouch. Why not use a HTML parser instead? BeautifulSoup does this in one.

Comment: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`, `print(BeautifulSoup(data).prettify())`.

Comment: Obligatory link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/10077

Comment: I looked at HTMLParser, but I couldn't see how that would remove the special characters if you know what I mean. I want the program to be as portable as possible so I dislike using external modules if at all possible.

Comment: Last but not least, if your `data` value contains `b''`, then you called `str()` on a `bytes` value, instead of decoding it to a string. Don't do that either. And `str.splitlines()` does what your regular expression does with a built-in method.

Comment: @FredLarson: the OP is trying to split on line delimiters, hardly call for summoning Zalgo here. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Well, I saw "parse HTML" and "regular expression" in the same post. Maybe I was too quick on the trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are converting a `bytes` value to string:

```
data = str(data)
# This checks for a cruft and removes it if it exists.
if re.search("b'", data):
    data = data[2:-1]
```

which means that all line delimiters have been converted to their Python escape codes:

```
>>> str(b'\n')
"b'\n'"
```

That is a literal `b`, literal quote, literal `\` backslash, literal `n`, literal quote. You would have to split on `r'(\\n|\\r)'` instead, but most of all, you shouldn't turn bytes values to string representations here. Python produced the *representation* of the bytes value as a literal string you can paste back into your Python interpreter, which is not the same thing as the *value* contained in the object.

You want to *decode* to string instead:

```
if isinstance(data, bytes):
    data = data.decode('utf8')
```

where I am assuming that the data is encoded with UTF8. If this is data from a web request, the response headers quite often include the character set used to encode the data in the `Content-Type` header, look for the `charset=` parameter.

A response produced by the `urllib.request` module has an `.info()` method, and the character set can be extracted (if provided) with:

```
charset = response.info().get_param('charset')
```

where the return value is `None` if no character set was provided.

You don't need to use a regular expression to split lines, the `str` type has a dedicated method, [`str.splitlines()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

> Return a list of the lines in the string, breaking at line boundaries. This method uses the *universal newlines* approach to splitting lines. Line breaks are not included in the resulting list unless keepends is given and true.
>
> For example, `'ab c\n\nde fg\rkl\r\n'.splitlines()` returns `['ab c', '', 'de fg', 'kl']`, while the same call with `splitlines(True)` returns `['ab c\n', '\n', 'de fg\r', 'kl\r\n']`.